# Symfony 2 dynamic routing (e.g. for stores)

Tags: php, symfony, dynamic, routes

I'm new at Symfony 2, now I'm trying to get a dynamic routing, I mean really dynamic.

For example:

```
example.com/en/categoryLevel1/categoryLevel2/categoryLevel3/productId-ProductName
```

OR

```
example.com/en/categoryLevel1/categoryLevel2/productId-ProductName
```

OR

```
example.com/en/categoryLevel1/categoryLevel2/categoryLevel3/
```

The number of category levels (the category depth) have to be flexible to `100%`. It must be possible and able to use one level to twenty levels.

Where is the entry point to setup this (which classes are doing those routing stuff)?

Another example is:

routes on the old page:

example.com/{categoryLvl1}/{categoryLvl2}/.../p-{productId}

at the new page are some changes in the routes:

example.com/{lang}/{catLevel1}/{catLevel2}/.../{productId}-{productName}

how i do the regex, etc.. i know. But i can't find the routing process in symfony (better the pre-routing process). I would like to build an pre-routing class and fallback the "normal" symfony2 routing.  i have to match old and new, both are completely dynamic..  the old one is written in ZF1 (pretty easy for me) but symfony2 is a new area for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have a bundle that handles this type of URL, you might add the following in the bundle's `routing.yml` (I prefer yml, YMMV).

```
YourSomethingBundle_main_any:
    pattern:  /{request}
    defaults: { _controller: YourSomethingBundle:Main:dispatcher }
    requirements:
        request: ".*"
```

Important: This is a “catch-all”, letting you process the actual request path in your controller. You should either prefix the `pattern` path, or load this bundle after all other bundles, or other routes will no longer work.

As per SF2 conventions, you would now have a `MainController` class with a `dispatcherAction` method:

```
<?php

namespace Your\SomethingBundle\Controller;

use \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function dispatcherAction($request='')
    {
        $request = preg_split('|/+|', trim($request, '/'));

        // ... and so on.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, this is what i m searching for! :)